# The number of guests AT birthday parties IS

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I was asked about weddings and birthday parties in my country. I said the following:

*"The **number** of guests at birthday parties **is** not as high as at weddings."*

I have two questions about this sentence:

1. Since the subject is 'number' was I correct to say 'is' here?
2. When talking about parties/weddings, do we use 'at'?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. “Number” is singular. “Is” is correct.
2. Yes, “at” works.

Your sentence is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Since *number* is a *singular* noun, yes, *is* is correct (*The number is...*). If the sentence had started (for example) *The numbers of guests on each of the first three days of the tournament...*, where *numbers* is *plural*, you would have used *are* (*The numbers are*).

In general, American English does use *at* when referring to **event** attendance. When referring to presence at named **locations**, it is common to use *in* - but there are exceptions (e.g., it is proper to say that one is either *in the park* or *at the park*).

Comment: By 'named locations' do you mean something like New York Central Park? For example, "He is in the Central Park."

Comment: No; with proper names, you use the proper name as it normally appears. But if you're referring to a specific location generically - "the stadium", "the park", "the mall", you use the _the_. You would, however, say that _He is in Central Park_ or _He is at Carnegie Hall_.